# Does the phrase "A of B and C" mean " (A of B) and C " or it means " A of (B and C) "?

Tags: grammar

Does the phrase "A of B and C" mean (A of B) and C  or  it means A of (B and C)

Cheers

Joee

Comment: Some examples would be helpful. The meaning might change according what people, places or things A, B and C are.

Comment: examples : seeds of an apple and orange; seeds of apple and an orange; seeds of an apple and an orange; seeds of apple and orange. Note: the determiners of noun apple and noun orange vary and sometimes the determiner is not present.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the phrase “A of B and C” mean “ (A of B) and C ” or it means “ A of (B and C) ”?

It's ambiguous.  For example, one might understand "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland" in either of two ways:

- the United Kingdom of [Great Britain and Northern Ireland], or
- [the United Kingdom of Great Britain] and [Northern Ireland].

In this case, the first interpretation is correct (i.e. the United Kingdom consists of both the entities mentioned, not just one of them).  But the phrase itself and similar phrases are ambiguous and can be understood in either way.

Much the same ambiguity applies to the examples you subsequently asked about:

> seeds of an apple and an orange

Ambiguous also.  You'd have to judge from context whether it meant seeds of an apple and of an orange or whether it meant seeds of an apple, and an orange.

> seeds of apple and orange

Not a very likely formulation, but remains ambiguous.

> seeds of apples and oranges

Again, you have to judge from context.

> seeds of an apple and orange

The ambiguity remains.  The inconsistent use of articles might suggest these are two separate items, although as "orange" is rarely used as a mass noun, the exact meaning is unclear.

As we've seen, there are ways to things clearer.  If you added a comma ("seeds of apples, and oranges") then the oranges would be a separate item.  (Similarly if you changed it to "oranges and seeds of apples".)  If you added "of" ("seeds of apples and of oranges") then the meaning would be "seeds of apples and seeds of oranges".  Without the comma, there may be a tendency to assume that you mean "seeds of apples and seeds of oranges", but it's hard to be sure, particularly out of context.

"Apple seeds" is a more common expression than "seeds of apples".  "Apple and orange seeds" (without a preceding article) would generally be interpreted as "apple seeds and orange seeds" (partly because "apple" is relatively uncommon as a mass noun), but again, one can't be sure.

Comment: examples : seeds of an apple and orange; seeds of apple and an orange; seeds of an apple and an orange; seeds of apple and orange. Note: the determiners of noun apple and noun orange vary and sometimes the determiner is not present.

Comment: Very timely answer! Apparently, President Macron yesterday chose to interpret *United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland* the "perverse" way (i.e. - according to him, Northern Ireland isn't "really" part of the United Kingdom; it's a separate entity, eminently suitable for use as a political football).